# Angular CLI freezes computer occasionaly on ng serve

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-4

I am having a problem with `ng serve`. When I run it on my angular project, about 10% of time, it will freeze during the process and also whole computer freezes. Sometimes it unfreeze after some time (from 20 seconds to 120 seconds) and successfully compiles, sometimes I need to manually power off the computer. I have encountered this problem on 2 computers already.

One thing I noticed is when the computer is frozen, the LED indicator of HDD usage on my case keeps shining. Do you have any idea, what could be the cause of this freeze? Could it be some error/bug in my project? I call `ng serve` from my WebStorm IDE, which is already very RAM consuming, so could it be a result of not enough RAM memory? I've tried to log outputs of ng serve to file in case of freeze, but it shows no errors.

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS || Linux Mint 20
Angular CLI: 10.0.3
Node: 14.14.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: 10.1.6
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

@angular-devkit/architect         0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/core              10.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.3
@angular/cli                      10.0.3
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.8
@schematics/angular               10.0.3
@schematics/update                0.1000.3
rxjs                              6.6.3
typescript                        3.9.7
webpack                           4.43.0
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? There are some memory leaks in development, and it might eat all your memory (your disk would be 100% used because of swap). If I am correct just kill that tab and reopen it.

Comment: How much ram do you have in total?

Comment: @BojanKogoj I use Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: @code-gorilla I have 8GB of RAM.

Comment: I would say it is not enough, given that the operating system, webstorm, a browser and more is running. Have you checked how the ram usage develops while your are using `ng serve`? How much ram is still free before you start `ng serve`?

Comment: @code-gorilla before ```ng serve``` about 50% RAM free. While using ```ng serve```, about 25% RAM free. So I suppose the problem could appear when I am using more programmes, so I have even less RAM available? Do you think it could be the cause?

Comment: So I'm pretty sure that the problem is that your ram is full and your computer becomes unresponsive because of it. The question still is if/why your `ng serve` process growing, e.g. because of some issue when the hot reloader updates the code. Does the ram usage of `ng serve` increase while your are developing?

Comment: 8GB is not enough for all you run. Restart browser and Webstorm every now and then to get memory back.

Comment: @code-gorilla while ```ng serve``` is listening to updates, the free RAM is about 20-30%, with occasional spikes (when compiling changes), when free RAM is about 10-15%. But it does not look like it keeps growing in terms of RAM usage (or at least not a big grow). However, I am going to buy additional 8GB of RAM, as I wanted to do it already for a long time. Thank you for taking your time!:)