# cannot serve angular 15 app in ubuntu22.04

Tags: angular, ubuntu-22.04

I'm using angular 15 in ubuntu 22.04.[my angular config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8DeK.png) when i try to serve build or test my project. i just keeps loading until it finally kills.
my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "a",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "cypress:run": "cypress run"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@cypress/schematic": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "cypress": "latest",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  }
}
```

does anyone know why this is happening and/or how to fix it

Comment: Sounds like same problem: [angular freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64445221/angular-cli-freezes-computer-occasionaly-on-ng-serve)

Enough RAM?

Comment: i currently have 1gb of ram in my digital ocean server. is this enough? if not how much would u recommend to have for a angular server.

Comment: There is no need for "Angular Server". During the development you can use `ng serve`. As soon as your are ready to deploy, just build with `npm run build`. And upload the artifacts to a simple webhosting/http Server. Not much RAM needed.

Comment: i already have a angular project witch i want to put on a server. i just wanted to test if i could make 1 in the server since my current project wast working when i cloned it to the server. then i noticed i couldn't serve the app anyway.